# How to define property with a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have three steps in a form that I want to show sequentially, so I created three components - one for each step of the process.

My app.js file:

```
import LocationList from './components/LocationList.vue';
import ChooseTime from './components/ChooseTime.vue';
import ChooseMethod from './components/ChooseMethod.vue';

Vue.component('location-list', LocationList);
Vue.component('choose-time', ChooseTime);
Vue.component('choose-method', ChooseMethod);

let store = {
    isVisible: {
        steps: {
            one: true,
            two: false,
            three: false,
        }
    }
};

new Vue({
    el: '#app-order',

    data: store,

    router
});
```

Now, when my one and only route is called,

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

```
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/order',
        component: require('./views/Order.vue')
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

all these components are being loaded properly. The issue is that when I try to `v-show` them one at a time:

Order.vue:

```
<template>

    // ...

    <location-list v-show="isVisible.steps.one"></location-list>
    <choose-time v-show="isVisible.steps.two"></choose-time>
    <choose-method v-show="isVisible.steps.three"></choose-method>

    // ...

</template>

<script>
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The error message I receive is:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "isVisible" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

But when I check within Vue's browser extension, isVisible is defined within the root element?

[image: error]

As you can see it is in the root-element, but not inside the Order view though.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is `isVisible` referenced in one of the step components templates?

Comment: No, I just have a basic file structure like `<template></template> <script></script> <style></style>`. I do not reference `isVisible` anywhere in it

Comment: I don't see a problem with what's posted so far.

Comment: I do, but it is a private one unfortunately. I could replicate the issue later and share it in a repo, but I just updated the post with some more detailed information. I think the issue might be because the Order view does not include the isVisible property, only the root parent element. I am fairly new with Vue, so I sorry about this!

Comment: Yes, that would be the issue. You need to pass `isVisible` down to the `Order.vue`, or define it there entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue, child components do not have direct access to data defined in their parents. You have to pass the data down.

I think you would probably save yourself a little trouble if you just defined `isVisible` in `Order.vue`. However, if you want to leave it where it is, you need to pass it into the component.

One easy way to do that is to define `isVisble` as a property of `Order.vue` and then pass it through your `router-view`.

```
<router-view :is-visible="isVisible"></router-view>
```

There are other ways of passing props to routes that are [defined in the router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html).

The reason I say you would save your self some trouble defining `isVisible` in `Order.vue` is because whenever you want to change the values of your steps, you will need to do it at the root as you currently have it defined.

Comment: I agree, I feel I like it would be better to define it within the component as well. I would just move the isVisible object to Order.vue and have it inside a mounted() method?

Comment: @Chris just define it in the components data. `data(){ return { isVisible: ...}}`

Comment: Thanks so much Bert!